# Does C++ include all headers a included header file includes?

Tags: c++, header-files

In this example code, I have 3 files:

testHeader.h:

```
void hello() {  }
```

file1.h:

```
#include "testHeader.h"
#include <iostream>
void sayHi() { std::cout << "hi" << std::endl; }
```

file2.h:

```
#include "file1.h"
void sayHello() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
```

If `file1.h` includes `testHeader.h` and `file2.h` includes `file1.h`, do `testHeader.h` and its functions become accessible in `file2.h`? What about `<iostream>` and its functions?

Comment: Yes, of course. `#include` is literally ctrl-v.

Comment: You can get into problems if your includes form a loop and you have circular dependencies between headers but that is going off topic.

Comment: It's a good practice to make each header self sufficient however. You don't want a change in a header to randomly break some other possibly lesser used header.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is, to use forward declarations rather than `#include`ing other headers if avoidable. Anyways one should use `#pragma once` or header guards (`#ifndef` `#endif` pair), as it's expectable to be done by the standard library headers.

Comment: Placing definitions inside headers can lead to breaking [the one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule). See [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) and [`extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) for help avoiding this problem.

Comment: @user4581301: [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) is also relevant there (outside class definitions). It'll be multiply defined, but each compilation unit will have a version with purely internal linkage (without necessarily being inlined).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless protected by preprocessor guards in weird ways, yes, you get them all. `#include` is largely a preprocessor trick, roughly equivalent to dumping the text of the include into the source code, and it's transitive; if you `#include <a.h>`, you get the expanded form of `a.h`, including the preprocessor expanded form of all its includes, all their includes, etc., etc. ad infinitum, in a single pass.

Note that it's still a good idea to explicitly include all the things you rely on directly; sure, the other `.h` files might `#include <vector>` today, but that's no guarantee the next release will have them if they're not a necessary part of the API being exposed.

It's also worth noting that preprocessor include guards (and/or `#pragma once`) is used almost universally to mean a `.h` file's contents don't get included twice (by convention, not a guarantee; in the case of poorly written `.h` files, or weird ones designed for multiple inclusion with different preprocessor setups it won't be obeyed); there is little to no cost to re-including a header in the `.cpp` that it already got from a `.h` you included. On older compilers, without `#pragma once` and with no special handling for include guards, it might have to load the header a second time, see the guard, and dump nothing on the second include; many newer compilers are smart enough to avoid even that cost. Point is, don't try to optimize by avoiding redundant `#include`s; every file should have the complete set of `#include`s needed for the things used in that file, no more, no less.

Comment: It's maybe noteworthy that all that happens in a _single pass_ (in case your description isn't already clear enough about that).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Sure. Not sure it really matters to the OP's case, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you work on older compilers, without #pragma once, then try to do as following.

--- file1.h ---

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

#include "testHeader.h"
#include <iostream>
void sayHi();

#endif
```

--- file1.cpp ---

```
#include "file.h"
void sayHi() { std::cout << "hi" << std::endl; }
```

--- file2.h ---

```
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H

#include "file1.h"
#include <iostream>
void sayHello();

#endif
```

**You shouldn't make a body of function in HEADER file. It might cause a compile error for multiple links for the same function. Please write function' prototype and body into Header and Source file seperately.**

Comment: It's okay to place the body of a function in the header *if* the function is `inline` (explicitly, or implicitly in the case of `constexpr` functions or functions defined within the scope of a class/struct/union definition), `static`, or both. The former means it's rarely realized as an actual function (the contents are inlined at each call site) while the latter means each file including that header gets its own unique copy of the function that's not visible to other compilation units; either way, no conflicts.